# Red lightbulb warning

Tags: javascript, function, google-sheets

I keep getting this red lightbulb message in the sheets script editor every time it runs. Is there something wrong with the code? It seems to work and doesn't take very long to execute.

**Method Range.getValue is heavily used by the script**

The script uses a method which is considered expensive. Each invocation generates a time consuming call to a remote server. That may have critical impact on the execution time of the script, especially on large data. If performance is an issue for the script, you should consider using another method, e.g. Range.getValues()

```
function Merge() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Expense Index');
  var lastrow=sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:F"+(lastrow+1));
var k=3;

  for (var i = 4; i <=lastrow+1; i++) {
  var  val1=range.getCell(i-1, 1).getValue();
  var  val2=range.getCell(i, 1).getValue();

     if(val1!==val2){
     if(!(sheet.getRange('A'+k+':A'+(i-1)).isPartOfMerge())){
     sheet.getRange('A'+k+':A'+(i-1)).mergeVertically();
     range.getCell((i-1), 6).setValue('=SUM(E'+k+':E'+(i-1)+')');
     }  
     k=i;
     }
 }
 sheet.getRange("A1:F"+(lastrow+1)).setHorizontalAlignment('center');
 sheet.getRange("A1:F"+(lastrow+1)).setVerticalAlignment('middle')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Apps Script has [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) recommended by the development team. Making repeat range calls is expensive in operation. It's much better to batch your range data and then iterate the Object that is returned.

Right now, you're requesting 2 Objects on each loop. It's more efficient to get all the data as a single object. So, change:

```
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:F"+(lastrow+1));
```

to

```
// range.getValues() returns a 2D array you can loop through in one call.
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:F"+(lastrow+1)).getValues();
```

and loop through the object using bracket notation.

Comment: Total noob, I can't seem to figure out how to loop through the object, I've tried a bunch of things but get this error more often than not.

TypeError: Cannot find function getCell in object Expense

Comment: How is your sheet set up? I can update with a sample loop to help out.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm reading your script right, if two cells in column A match, merge the rows and sum the cost, right?

Comment: Yeah, it vertically merges cells that match in column A and sums the columns that just merged vertically for column D into the last row of column E